# Account preferences in Android 2.2 per account, not account type

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo

I'm developing an Android application and have one account authenticator with preferences.
But when I add two accounts of my type, then the preferences are shared between them. How can I define preferences, so that they could be set for each account separately?

Thanks in advance!

Przemek

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `Preferences` for this purpose!

You should be using `AccountManager.setUserData()` and `AccountManager.getUserData()` to store your stuff; this makes your settings secure (`AccountManager` is storing it) and you are passing the `Account`, so everything is matched up correctly, and all the bookkeeping is done when the user deletes accounts.

Comment: Thanks. It was long time ago, when I worked on those things. Your answer sounds good, so I'll check it in a free time and mark the issue as answered.